# Zywall ATP - Access Forward but no answer through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall

I'm looking for a solution to my problem but all my tests have failed.

Basically, I want to reach a device (10.200.195.70) on a subnet (10.200.195.0/24) via my VPN (10.200.200.0/24).

If I connect my computer directly to the subnet, I can ping 10.200.195.70 and everything works fine.

When I connect my VPN via the Zyxel SecuExtender, I receive an IP address in the range 10.200.200.0. I have created an SSL-VPN (10.200.200.0) -> LAN (10.200.195.0) test policy route, but when I ping 10.200.195.70 I get no response.

However, in the ATP 800 logs I see "Access Forward" during my test.

What could this be about?

Comment: I have not used this setup.  One thing I have seen over time is using a subnet mask on the client app that does not include the remote site (10.200.195.0) subnet.  Check that in your app.